# Capture JSON at VB.NET REST

Tags: json, vb.net, wcf, rest, vb.net-2010

I have 2 checkboxes. I need to capture the checkboxes clicked and send it to REST SERVICE, I am able to capture checkboxes clicked at fnt end but I don't know how to capture it in the REST (VB.Net).

Below is the front end file:

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" class = "checkBoxProp" id = "1" name="checkBoxProp" value="1">Graph1<br> 
<input type="checkbox" class = "checkBoxProp" id = "2" name="checkBoxProp" value="2">Graph4<br> 
<input id="btnGetResponse" type="button" value="ClickMe!"/> 
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#btnGetResponse").click(function()
{

    var ids = $('.checkBoxProp:checked').map(function() {
        return this.value;
      }).get();
      console.log(JSON.stringify(ids.join()));
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:51349/SMS_Rest.svc/v1/usercheckboxes",
        data:  {ids: ids} ,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response)
        {
           alert('success');
        },
        failure: function(response) 
        {
            alert('fail');
        }
        });
    });
```

So how to capture JSON at REST.

```
 Public Function CheckBoxDetails(ByVal requestData As **WHAT TO WRITE HERE**) As String Implements iSMS_Rest.CheckBoxDetails
  // SOME LOGIC
    End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method at server-side should be a POST and you should capture the data from body of the request instead of querystring. So, the argument list should have [FromBody] attribute and it would be  abetter way if you can create a input model class with similar structure as the input data and have similar properties, use that object as the parameter to the POST method.